# Diophantine equation: choosing the right modulus to prove an equation cannot be satisfied

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations

I was looking at [this problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1751770/there-does-not-exist-any-integer-m-such-that-3n23n7-m3), which asks to show that there are no $m,n \in \mathbb Z$ such that
$$3n^2+3n+7 = m^3.$$
The result follows immediately from considering the equation modulo $9$ and enumerating the possibilities. But what if we somehow missed $9$ and instead considered other moduli? In other words, we would be aiming to find a $k \in \mathbb Z$ for which the sets $\{3n^2 + 3n + 7:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\{m^3:m\in\mathbb Z\}$ are disjoint modulo $k$, thereby proving the impossibility of finding such $m,n$.

I've looked through all $k \in [2, 5000]$, and the winners are precisely the multiples of $9$. Why is this so?

The main question I have is this:

> Is it true that $\{3n^2 + 3n + 7:n\in\mathbb Z\}$ and $\{m^3:m\in\mathbb Z\}$ are disjoint modulo $k$ if and only if $k \equiv 0 \pmod 9$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a sketch. For all but finitely many primes $p$, your equation gives rise to an [elliptic curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve) $\bmod p$. To see this very explicitly, rewrite it as

$$81n^2 + 81n + 27 \cdot 7 = 27m^3$$

and substitute $z = 9n, x = 3m$ to get

$$z^2 + 9z + 27 \cdot 7 = x^3.$$

Now complete the square to get

$$\left( z + \frac{9}{2} \right)^2 = x^3 - 27 \cdot 7 + \frac{81}{4} = x^3 - \frac{3^3 \cdot 5^2}{2^2}.$$

Substituting $y = z + \frac{9}{2}$ produces an elliptic curve $\bmod p$ for all primes $p$ except possibly $p = 2, 3, 5$.

The [Hasse-Weil bound](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/hasse-weil-bound/) implies that when $p \neq 2, 3, 5$ this curve has at least $p - 2 \sqrt{p}$ points on it, so for all primes $p \ge 7$ there is a solution $\bmod p$. (This is the least trivial step in the argument, and it really uses the fact that we have an elliptic curve and not just some polynomial.) Using [Hensel's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hensel%27s_lemma) will allow us to lift these to solutions $\bmod p^k$, and using the Chinese remainder theorem gives us solutions $\bmod n$ where $n$ isn't divisible by $2, 3, 5$.

Now the only moduli left to investigate are powers of $2, 3, 5$. For $2$ and $5$ you can find solutions by hand and use Hensel's lemma, which leaves only $3$.